# Loop through tables last row and set the data cell values

Tags: jquery

I am using `clone()` to add new row to the table.  But the clone is copying the `<td>` ID values also.  How can I change the ids and the values of the rows that were copied? Also, I have a `<select>` in one `<td>` cell how can I attach onchange event to this select.

Answer (score 1):

Just stock your clone in a variable, and after cloning, before inserting it in the DOM you just have to delete the`id` attribute (or change it)...

Answer (score 0):

```
clonedRow.find('*').attr('id', '');
```

to attach an event:

```
clonedRow.find('select').change(function() {});
```